# Akka-http-json "Unsupported Content-Type, supported: application/json"

Tags: json, scala, akka-http

I'm having trouble using a custom JSON marshaller/unmarshaller. This much works fine:

```
trait EWorksJsonSupport extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit object IndividualJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Individual] {
    def write(individual: Individual) = JsObject(
      // blah blah blah
    )

    def read(value: JsValue): Individual = {
      // blah blah blah
    }
}
```

The problem is that `Unsupported Content-Type, supported: application/json` is returned as shown below:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentTypes._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity
import akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.ScalatestRouteTest
import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling._
import eworks.model.immutableModel.SpeciesAll
import eworks.model.mutableModel.{Individual, Individuals, VirtualWorld}
import eworks.model.{Fixtures, LoadableModel, SpeciesDefaultLike}
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.Matchers._
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import spray.json._

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class TestRest extends WordSpec with SpeciesDefaultLike with LoadableModel with ScalatestRouteTest with Fixtures with EWorksJsonSupport {    
  "EWorksJsonSupport" should {
    "work for Individuals" in {
      val jsObject: JsValue = harry.toJson
      val entity = HttpEntity(`application/json`, jsObject.toString)

      Post("/addIndividual", entity) ~> new RestHttp()(speciesDefaults).route ~> check {
        handled === true
        contentType === `application/json`
        status.intValue === 200

        val individual1 = Unmarshal(response.entity).to[Individual] 
        // ErrorFuture(akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller$UnsupportedContentTypeException: Unsupported Content-Type, supported: application/json)
        val individual2 = responseAs[Individual]
        responseAs[Individual] shouldBe harry
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to the solution is to call `complete` with the desired `ContentType`. Here is a method I wrote that provides an `HttpResponse` with `Content-Type` `application/json` along with the desired content, computed when `block` is evaluated:

```
@inline def wrap(block: => JsValue): StandardRoute =
  complete(
    try {
      HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, success(block)))
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, error(e.getMessage)))
    }
  )
```

I made a trait to encapsulate this handy utility method:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{ContentTypes, HttpEntity, HttpHeader, HttpResponse}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.{Directives, MediaTypeNegotiator, Route, StandardRoute, UnsupportedRequestContentTypeRejection}
import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling._
import spray.json._
import scala.collection.immutable.Seq

trait RestHttpSupport extends Directives {
  @inline def error  (msg: String): String = JsObject("error"   -> JsString(msg)).prettyPrint
  @inline def success(msg: String): String = JsObject("success" -> JsString(msg)).prettyPrint

  @inline def error  (msg: JsValue): String = JsObject("error"   -> msg).prettyPrint
  @inline def success(msg: JsValue): String = JsObject("success" -> msg).prettyPrint

  @inline def wrap(block: => JsValue): StandardRoute =
    complete(
      try {
        HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, success(block)))
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, error(e.getMessage)))
      }
    )

  @inline def completeAsJson[T](requestHeaders: Seq[HttpHeader])
                               (body: T => StandardRoute)
                               (implicit um: FromRequestUnmarshaller[T]): Route = {
    import akka.http.scaladsl.model.MediaTypes.`application/json`
    if (new MediaTypeNegotiator(requestHeaders).isAccepted(`application/json`)) {
      entity(as[T]) { body }
    } else {
      reject(UnsupportedRequestContentTypeRejection(Set(`application/json`)))
    }
  }

  @inline def postAsJson[T](body: T => StandardRoute)
                   (implicit um: FromRequestUnmarshaller[T]): Route = {
    (post & extract(_.request.headers)) { requestHeaders =>
      completeAsJson[T](requestHeaders) { body }
    }
  }
}
```

One the trait is mixed in, and assuming that implicit serializers built from `SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol` are in scope, an Akka HTTP path can be defined using the `wrap` method. All of this code is taken from [EmpathyWorks™](https://www.micronauticsresearch.com/empathyWorks.html) (which is not open source):

```
path("definedEvents") {
  get { wrap(allDefinedEvents.toJson) }
} ~
path("listIndividuals") {
  get { wrap(individuals.toJson) }
} ~
path("listSpecies") {
  get { wrap(speciesAll.toJson) }
} ~
path("listSpeciesNames") {
  get { wrap(speciesAll.collection.map(_.name).toJson) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change the content type you could:

```
    val stringR : String = Await.result(Unmarshal(r).to[String],Duration.Inf)
    val ind : Individual = Unmarshal(stringR).to[Individual]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpResponse` response you get from the `new RestHttp()(speciesDefaults).route` router by posting your entity to `/addIndividual` (as logged, see below) has `text/plain` as content-type, you should fix that. Also its content does not look like valid JSON (see below).

Response was:

```
HttpResponse(
    200 OK,
    List(),
    HttpEntity.Strict(
        text/plain; charset=UTF-8, 
        Individual added: harry is a human; (unborn); lifeStage 'adult'
    ), HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1)
)
```

Comment: I thought that declaring the Entity as `HttpEntity(`application/json`, jsObject.toString)` would set `Content-Type`. If not, how should I accomplish that?

I modified the code to match my current work in progress.

What you think should be JSON is the toString output, provided by IntelliJ IDEA in the IDE, which I pasted in to help understand. Seems that only confused things.

Where did you get that `HttpResponse` from?

Comment: Also, the test for `Content-Type` passed, which is confusing.

Comment: The problem is not with the entity `entity` you supply to the `Post("/addIndividual", entity)` call but with the entity that your application gives you back (the `response.entity`), this is of type `text/plain` and does not contain a valid JSON. You need to fix that, the issue is not in the part of the code snippet you listed there. I got the `HttpResponse` from your code snippet, prior to your last edit, it shows what the response was.

Comment: I made a gist of the server code that shows how I attempt (in vain) to set Content-Type and Accepts headers. What am I missing?
https://gist.github.com/mslinn/2b648122c85c12476b4f771101b4c6c2